# Disc not found when installing CentOS in VirtualBox

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine, centos

On Windows 7, I am trying to install CentOS (CentOS-6.2-i386-netinstall.iso) using [VirtualBox](http://virtualbox.org) however it says Disc not found after language selection.

Here's exactly what I'm getting: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G2b4cnMwMVc

Anybody knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The user interface of the installer is misleading.

With the netinstall image, you will need to provide a URL to install from (i.e. http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/i386/ ).

You probably want the minimal disc image instead: (i.e. CentOS-6.2-i386-minimal.iso).